# Loading options into dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a section of code that uses is supposed to append options to the drop down, however; the referenced drop down isn't getting populated.

```
teamsDropDown = #id;
function loadDropDown(data, teamsDropDown)
{
    var defaultValue;

    teamsDropDown.find("option").remove();
    var list = teamsDropDown;

    jQuery.each(data, function(index, item) {
        var listOptions = list;
        listOptions[listOptions.length] = new Option(item.Name, item.Value.replace(new RegExp("'", "g"), "&apos;"));
        if (item.IsDefaultValue) {
            defaultValue = item.Value;
        }
});
teamsDropDown.val(defaultValue).attr("selected", "selected");
}

function HTMLOptionElementFactory (text, value, defaultSelected, selected) {
    /// <signature>
    /// <param name='text' type='String' optional='true' />
    /// <param name='value' type='String' optional='true' />
    /// <param name='defaultSelected' type='Boolean' optional='true' />
    /// <param name='selected' type='Boolean' optional='true' />
    /// </signature>
    return Object.create(HTMLOptionElement);
}
```

Comment: Yes. They are supposed to be the same.

Comment: Where is this called from? With what data in `data`? In short, can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: There are two drop downs. This code happens when you the first drop down is changed -> populating the above dropdown